# why does my output come in hundreds when i want it in thousands

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class diceSimulation {

private static Random rollDice = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int ROLLCOUNT = 100000;
    final int SIDES = 12;
    int count, dice1, dice2;


    int [] doubleCounts = new int [SIDES];


    welcome ();


    for (count=1; count<=ROLLCOUNT;count++){

        dice1=roll(SIDES);
        dice2=roll(SIDES);

        if (dice1==dice2){
            doubleCounts[dice1-1]++;
        }

    }

    // Display results totals of paired rolls 
    for (int idx=0; idx<doubleCounts.length; idx++){
        System.out.format(" You rolled set of %d %d times\n",(idx+1), doubleCounts[idx]);
    }
}

private static int roll(int sides){
    return rollDice.nextInt(sides) +  1;
}

public static void welcome () {
    System.out.println("Here are your rolling dice percentages");
}
}
```

This is my code for a dice Simulation project where I'm supposed to check how many times does each side of dice rolls using 12 sides but for some reason my output for the code only gives me numbers in hundreds that don't add up to 10,000 which is the rollcount. Can someone fix that problem for me? I am sorry if my code is bad but i am new to coding and to stack overflow so please let me know if there is anything i can fix.

Comment: By convention programmers use `for (count=0; count<ROLLCOUNT;count++)`, this makes indexing arrays easier.

Comment: thanks its worked better now but still doesnt add up to 10000

Comment: can you you give us a sample output and a sample of what you want?

Comment: Are you expecting `10000` or `100000` ?  Note that pairs will only occur, on average, 1/6 times.  For 100K rolls, this would mean about 17K pairs.

Comment: the output i am looking for is having a percentage for each roll not just a number.

Comment: for example 10= 17.6 or like 9 = 10.1 like the probability for each roll using percent

Comment: the probability of each roll is `16.7%`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Ps0Zc

Comment: why is my output coming out with low numbers and not percentages does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When you roll two dice, the probability that you'll get a pair is just `16.7%` so if you rolled `100000` times, you'll likely get `16700` pairs. I believe your code is working how it should be.

Comment: @JohnYohana what did you do? how did you fixed it?

Comment: actually i did not i just figured out another problem i am going to take a screen shot of my out and show u the problem

Comment: why is my output coming out with low numbers?

Comment: this might be a dumb question so Im sorry but what do you mean by edited my code?  im still new to this coding world but i really am trying to learn @dranreb dino

Comment: @JohnYohana I tried your code and got results around 8000. I think your code is working just fine

Comment: change int ROLLCOUNT = 100000 to 10000 and you will see what i mean

Answer (score -1):

If you only care about double counts, the likelihood of rolling doubles is significantly less than 100000 on a 12 sided die, so you should not expect the doubles counts to sum to 100000.

Comment: ohh but is there a way that would make the output add up to 10000?

Comment: Why downvote?  answer is essentially identical to below.

Comment: Just press the up arrow